# How can I do 'google sign in' in Google Actions Console?

Tags: google-signin, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

[image]
How can I do 'google sign in' in Google Action Console?

When I created a project in 'actions console', I selected Smart Home and created a project. I want to use 'Google Sign In' because the OAuth process is complicated, but when I enter 'account linking', 'Google Sign In' should appear along with 'linking type', but it does not appear. The picture above is 'account linking' with the 'Google Sign In' feature I want and the picture below is my current situation. Can I use 'Google Sign In' to connect my account with a smart home?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first image attached above is from a documentation of non smart home actions. For smart home actions you need to use account linking.